# Doubly periodic solutions to $\frac{|\partial w|^2}{(1+|w|^2)^2} = C^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I am interested in solutions to $$\frac{|\partial_z w|^2}{(1+|w|^2)^2} = C^2$$ for $C>0$ a constant and $w = w(z,\bar z)$ is allowed to have poles. For example $\tan(|z|)$ is a solution. But I am interested in solutions that are *doubly periodic* in the complex plane, $w(z+\lambda) = w(z)$ for $\lambda \in \Lambda$, a lattice. Note $w$ need not be holomorphic.

> I am interested in this in the physics context of 2D skyrmion crystals, which are naturally a doubly periodic map from the plane to a sphere. In the natural $\Bbb{CP}^1$ parameterization of the sphere equations like this pop up all the time for interesting physics. I think it describes a function $w$ which maps the torus to the sphere in some "constant" way, since the natural Riemannian metric on the sphere is $\frac{|dz|^2}{(1+|z|^2)^2}$-- in fact any more insight into this equation would be helpful.

Comment: What is $\partial w$? Also, $\tan(\lvert z \rvert)$ is not differentiable at $z=0$, so what are exactly the conditions on a “solution”?

Comment: @WimC Thanks, I've updated $\partial$ to $\partial_z$. As a physicist I'd be happy with a solution which is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: For some context, I suggest adding a link to [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) in your question.

Answer (score 3):

The setting you are looking at is a map from a Riemann surface $\Sigma$, given by the 2-torus $\mathbb{T}^2$, to the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{CP}^1$. Let us call this map
$$
w: \mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{CP}^1.
$$
Suppose now that it is a holomorphic function (i.e. $w \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{T}^2)$, a meromorphic function on the torus). Then we compute the pullback of the volume form
$$
\omega=\frac{i}{2} \frac{du \wedge d\bar{u}}{(1+|u|^2)^2}
$$
associated with the Fubiny-Study metric you described. Now, we can compute as follows
$$
w^*\omega=\frac{i}{2}\det(Dw)\frac{dz \wedge d\bar{z}}{(1+|w|^2)^2}=\frac{i}{2}\frac{|\partial_zw|^2}{(1+|w|^2)^2}dz \wedge d\bar{z}.
$$
The equality $\det(Dw)=|\partial_zw|^2$ follows from holomorphicity.

In the theory of Skyrmions, you have a Skyrmion number, which is given by the topological degree of a map between oriented manifolds of the same dimension. Now, suppose $w$ satisfies your desired differential equation, we would have
$$
\pi \deg(w)=\pi \int_{\mathbb{T}^2}w^*\omega=\pi \int_{\mathbb{T}^2}\frac{i}{2}C^2 dz \wedge d\bar{z}=\pi C^2  \text{vol} (\mathbb{T}^2).
$$
By this argument, $ C^2  \text{vol} (\mathbb{T}^2) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since there are no holomorphic maps of degree one from the torus to the 2-sphere, we can sharpen this condition to
$$
 C^2 \text{vol} (\mathbb{T}^2)>1.
$$
This gives you the idea that, if you are looking for a holomorphic function in the classical sense, you have severe restrictions to $C^2>0$!!

If you are now looking for a holomorphic/meromorphic solution, you can express all these functions somehow in terms of the Weierstraß function $\wp$ on a given torus (i.e. lattice with prescribed periods). Unfortunately, I cant give you an answer ad-hoc, but this is a problem on elliptic functions.

In general, people in the math community for magnetic Skyrmions try to do a "Bogomolny re-arrangement" of the energy functional. You can find more on this in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.06285v2) as well as the corresponding research talk to it on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NK8lYdcTk7g), which is quite accessible. Long story short: you find a first order equation (different from yours), resembling the Cauchy-Riemann equations somehow, you solve it with complex analysis and then do gauge transformations. In general, this is a "twisted" holomorphic map, which does depend on both $z$ and $\bar{z}$. Standard complex analysis therefore no longer applies.

I am aware that I could not give a satisfying answer to your problem, but I hope this gives you some pointers. In particular, as your $\tan ( |z|)$ solution suggest, classic holomorphic functions are not what you are looking for. This sentence is also the quintessence of what I wanted to say.

Comment: I want to add that I am bad at solving ODE, so maybe there is a simple way to convert this into some exact DE (with $dx$ and $dy$), that I am not seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed discussion. Should the denominator of $\omega$ have $(1+|u|^2)^2$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I forgot about that

Comment: I edited the response, I am sorry I could not provide you with a full answer, but I decided to answer with this survey, since no one else seemed  to give the answer you desired.